# C3.js chart doesn't read variable in load function

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, char, c3.js

I'm using C3.js library and when I want add in the line chart one value dynamically, I call the function `updateChartC3(action, values)` with receives from PHP by `AJAX` and inside the function `updateChartC3(action, values)` I call the `load()` function to update the chart.

Doesn't work using the variable `"values"` (1st option). In the 2nd option, work very well.

I only want work with the first option.

```
var chart = '';

function startChart(columns_, positions, pcs, _height) {

  chart = c3.generate({
    bindto: '#chart-div',
    size: {
      height: _height
    },
    data: {
      bindto: '#chart',
      columns: columns_,
      order: 'asc'
    },
    zoom: {
      enabled: false
    },
    transition: {
      duration: 1000
    },
    axis: {
      x: {
        label: {
          text: "XKB",
          position: 'outer-center'
        },
        type: 'category',
        categories: pcs,
        tick: {
          centered: true
        }
      },
      y: {
        label: {
          text: 'Position',
          position: 'inner-middle'
        },
        tick: {
          values: positions
        },
        inverted: true,
        allowDecimals: false
      }
    }
  });
}

function updateChartC3(action, values) {
  // values = [ [ 'taripeco',18,14,12,'p','p', 'p' ] ]
  // 1st option - work
  if (action == 'add') {
    chart.load({
      columns: [
        ['taripeco', 18, 14, 12, 'p', 'p', 'p']
      ]
    });
  }

  // 2nd option- doesn't work
  if (action == 'add') {
    chart.load({
      columns: values
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: If you add console.log(values) at the beginning of *updateChartC3*, what does it print exactly?

Comment: can you try using clone of `values` in `updateChartC3(..)` ?

Comment: The problem is solved.
I had a problem with encoding. So I used the function ut8_encode() in PHP and it was ok